# Entity Framework - Database table Join in Linq to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities

I have two database table called employee and employee detail. and i use entityframwork.

i want to make a edit page which contains both table fields. Now when i click on grid view (having detail of both the table) i passed primary id and make a join based on it.

join detail is below

```
var list = (from g in db.Employee
                   join d in db.db.EmployeeDetail on g.EGID equals d.EGID
                   where g.EGID == id
                   select new CombineModel
                     {
                          EE_GENERAL = g,
                          EE_DEMOGRAPHIC = d
                     });
```

on above code "CombineModel" is class contain property with two table fields.

```
public class CombineModel
{
    public Employee EE_GENERAL { get; set; }
    public EmployeeDetail EE_DEMOGRAPHIC { get; set; }

}
```

now when i return a view of my edit page by passing "list" it shows me error and i unable to get data of my join. my edit view is bind with combinemodel.

Please guide me how i can type cast above list or get detail of list in view.

Below is Employee Class

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(Employee_Validation))]
public partial class Employee
{

}

public class Employee_Validation
{
    public Decimal EGID { get; set; }
    public Decimal CID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee ID is required")]
    public String EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Effective Date is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

    public String AddOper { get; set; }

    public DateTime ChgDate { get; set; }

    public String ChgOper { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }


    [StringLength(15)]
    public String MiddleName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public String CheckName { get; set; }

    public Int32 SSNO { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one security group.")]
    public String SecurityGroup { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one security level.")]
    public Byte SecurityLevel { get; set; }

    public Byte EESequence { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Change Type is required")]
    public Byte ChangeType { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public String OptionalComments { get; set; }

}
```

Below is EmployeeDetail class

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeDetail_Validation))]
public partial class EmployeeDetail
{ 

}

public class EmployeeDetail_Validation
{

    public Decimal DemographicId { get; set; }
    public Decimal CID { get; set; }
    public Decimal EGID { get; set; }

    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public String AddOper { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChgDate { get; set; }
    public String ChgOper { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birthdate is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public String NickName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address1 is required")]
    public String Address1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public String Address2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public String Address3 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public String City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one State.")]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public String State { get; set; }

    public String Zip { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
    [Display(Name = "Email address*")]
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one Gender.")]
    public String Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one Marital Status.")]     
    public String MaritalStatus { get; set; }


    [StringLength(200)]
    public String SpouseName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SpouseBirth { get; set; }

    public Int32 SpouseSSNO { get; set; }

    public Int32 EEOEthnic { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one EEOJob.")]
    public Int32 EEOJob { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one Citizen.")]  
    public Boolean Citizen { get; set; }

    public Decimal HomePhone { get; set; }

    [Range(0,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage="Please enter proper MobilePhone.")]
    public Decimal MobilePhone { get; set; }

    public Decimal OfficePhone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public String OfficeExt { get; set; }

    [Range(0,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage="BldgNo is too longer.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Building Number is required")]
    public Decimal BldgNo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Emergency Contact is required")]
    public String EmergContact { get; set; }

    public Decimal EmergPhone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No Of Childeren is required")]
    public Int32 NoOfChilderen { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Can you show `Employee` and `EmployeeDetail` Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as below

```
var list = (from g in db.Employee
   join d in db.db.EmployeeDetail on g.EGID equals d.EGID
   where g.EGID == id
   select new CombineModel
     {
          EE_GENERAL.PropertyName = g.ColumnName,
          EE_DEMOGRAPHIC.PropertyName = d.ColumnName
     });
```

Comment: i tried it but i am unable to access property of EE_GENERAL or EE_DEMOGRAPHIC

Comment: Should that be  `select new CombineModel  { EE_GENERAL=g, EE_DEMOGRAPHIC=d  }